# Building python package does not include src

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to build my Python package and distribute it to PyPi, however I'm having a problem with the actual `python -m build` command: it looks like it's not adding the actual `src` dir to the package!

Package structure:

```
|   .gitignore
|   LICENSE
|   pyproject.toml
|   README.md
|   setup.cfg
|   
|---src
|   |   sqlcontroller.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   L---sqlcontroller.egg-info
|           dependency_links.txt
|           PKG-INFO
|           SOURCES.txt
|           top_level.txt
...
```

`python -m build` command output:

```
...
creating 'C:\Users\mikec\Documents\Python\sqlcontroller\dist\tmp1x7mg4gg\sqlcontroller-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel' to it
adding 'sqlcontroller-0.0.1.dist-info/LICENSE'
adding 'sqlcontroller-0.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
adding 'sqlcontroller-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'
adding 'sqlcontroller-0.0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'
adding 'sqlcontroller-0.0.1.dist-info/RECORD'
removing build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
Successfully built sqlcontroller-0.0.1.tar.gz and sqlcontroller-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Opening up the .tar.gz file I can see that the 'src' folder only contains:
`sqlcontroller.egg-info`

I tried building both from outside/inside the venv, so I don't know what's wrong.

Here is my setup.cfg

```
...
[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages=find:

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to solve it!
Changed the last section of `setup.cfg` from

```
...
[options]package_dir=
    =src
packages=find:

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

to

```
...
[options]
packages=find:
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Was using `setup.py`. And it just wouldn't work right no matter what I did with the options:

```
packages=find_packages(
    where='src',
    include=['mypackage'],
),
```

Package would come out empty. And when I did `graft src` in `MANIFEST.in`, the package would install as `src` with my actual package inside of it.

Migrating my package config from `setup.py` to `pyproject.toml` format, using [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#package-discovery), made everything work right:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["mypackage*"]
```

Package installs correctly, and I am not grafting anything through `MANIFEST.in` anymore